# strings in python requests "i want to exract the steps from json"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

this is the JSON I am getting from the website :

```
[
{
  "id":"8-23p-0",
  "step":"",
  "html":"<p>1</p>",
  "link":"",
  "commentCount":0
},
{
  "id":"8-23p-1",
  "step":"1",
  "html":"<p>2</p>",
  "link":"",
  "commentCount":0
},
{
  "id":"8-23p-2",
  "step":"2",
  "html":"<p>3</p>",
  "link":"",
  "commentCount":0
},
{
  "id":"8-23p-3",
  "step":"3",
  "html":"<p>4</p>",
  "link":"",
  "commentCount":0
},
{
  "id":"8-23p-4",
  "step":"4",
  "html":"<p>5</p>",
  "link":"",
  "commentCount":0
}
```

]

and I am writing this code to get all the HTML from that

```
html_values = []
  for i in answer2:
html_values.append(i.get("html"))
```

by the above code i am getting all the html with type of list

but I want to add a heading for every step like :

expected output :

```
<h>step 1</h>  
<p>1</p>
<h>step 2</h> 
<p>2</p>
<h>step 3</h> 
<p>3</p>
<h>step 4</h> 
<p>4</p>
<h>step 5</h> 
<p>5</p>
```

I want to get the output like above please help me Thanks in before

Comment: why are all your p values 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the `step` value from your JSON, you can use a list comprehension with an `f-string` to format it:

```py
html_values = [f'<h>step {a["step"]}</h>{a["html"]}' for a in answer2]
```

Output:

```py
[
 '<h>step </h><p>1</p>',
 '<h>step 1</h><p>2</p>',
 '<h>step 2</h><p>3</p>',
 '<h>step 3</h><p>4</p>',
 '<h>step 4</h><p>5</p>'
]
```

If however you want the step number to reflect the entry in the list, then you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to generate the step numbers e.g.

```py
html_values = [f'<h>step {i}</h>{a["html"]}' for i, a in enumerate(answer2, 1)]
```

Output:

```py
[
 '<h>step 1</h><p>1</p>',
 '<h>step 2</h><p>2</p>',
 '<h>step 3</h><p>3</p>',
 '<h>step 4</h><p>4</p>',
 '<h>step 5</h><p>5</p>'
]
```

In both cases you can get the entire output as a string using [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) e.g.

```py
print(''.join(html_values))
```

Comment: how can I send all the output steps to an HTML code because its again giving me the list i want to pars this list to a HTML code

Comment: @BalajiKotni see the last line in my answer `print(''.join(html_values))`

Comment: hi sir can you help me n this question, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230015/display-a-countdown-for-the-python-sleep-function-in-discord-embed-in-python

Comment: @BalajiKotni sorry - I don't really know anything about discord.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare the step heading with the step value which you get in above json.

check below code:

```
html_values = []
for i in answer2:
    step = i.get('step')
    step = "<h>step %s</h>" % step
    html_values.append(step)
    html_values.append(i.get("html"))
```