# Display a countdown for the python sleep function in discord embed in python

Tags: python, discord.py

hi all I am doing one discord bot

I need to send one countdown it's like a cooldown embed after every request

I did this code but I don't know how to add this in my embed

```
 for i in range(60,0,-1):
     print(f"{i}", end="\r", flush=True)
     time.sleep(1)
```

this is my embed :

```
embed_processing = discord.Embed(
                title = ('please wait 1min we are processing your request time '),
                description=('Jaffa_the_warrior server'),
                colour = discord.Color.orange()
            )
            processingmessage = await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed_processing)
```

please help me i want to add a timer in the title

Comment: Have you tried to define your method? You can also just edit the message after a certain amount of time. Remember that `time.sleep` is pretty outdated, try to use `asyncio.sleep`

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def count(ctx, duration:int):
  msg = await ctx.send("Started")
  for i in range(duration, -1, -1):
    m, s = divmod(i, 60)
    await msg.edit(content="{0:02}:{1:02}".format(m, s))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

This is the timer command but not working good if called more then 1.

Comment: I tried to run this on my bot and it works perfectly. Can you share the code?

Comment: actually why you send is when a user send! count 5 then it will count but I need to start  the countdown immediately after  a user send a msg  this is my replit link please help me https://replit.com/join/hmvkdkae-balajikotni